# Join table with another table in a seperate database using NHibernate Query Language HQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, nhibernate, hql

I'm trying to join a table from another database using NHibernate. I basically prefix the table name with the DB name which I have done in the mapping files before and it has worked.

Please see my code below:

```
query.CreateAlias("OtherDatabase.SiteProduct","OtherDatabase.SiteProduct", JoinType.InnerJoin);
```

However, I get the following error message:

> NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: OtherDatabase of: XXX.XXXXX.Core.Domain.Catalog.Product

Is this possible to do in NHibernate? I'm assuming since there is no foreign key that ties the two tables together that maybe I need to specify what column the two tables need to be joined on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with other DB/Table *(accessible with current connection)* is supported. The thing here is.. the path to such table must come from mapping.

We can use either standard mapped Class, or we can introduce just an dynamic dictinoary mapping. E.g.

```
<class entity-name="OtherDBTable" table="[otherDB].[schema].[Table]" ... >
  <id       name="ID"           column="id"      type="Int32" />
  <property name="PropertyName" column="ColName" type="String" />
  ...
</class>
```

#### JOIN without mapped relation

> Despite of the title .. about HQL .. the broken statement
>
> ```
> query.CreateAlias("...
> ```
>
> seems to belong to `CreateriaQuery`... which we will use to JOIN this table

So, let's create standard CriteriaQuery

```
var query = session.CreateCriteria<MyInnerEntity>("rootAlias");
```

And we can join it to the dynamically mapped other DB/Table like this

```
query.CreateEntityAlias("otherAlias",
    Restrictions.EqProperty("rootAlias.OtherId", "otherAlias.ID"),
    JoinType.InnerJoin,
    "OtherDBTable"
);
```

and we can get the results

```
query.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.Property("rootAlias.ID"))
    .Add(Projections.Property("rootAlias.OtherId"))
    .Add(Projections.Property("otherAlias.ID"))
    .Add(Projections.Property("otherAlias.PropertyName"))
);
```

and finally we can read it as a list of array (or transform it ...)

```
var list = query.List<object[]>();
```

#### JOIN with mapped relation

in case, that our mapping to otherDB/Table would contain a relation (e.g. many-to-one) .. we could even use standard `CreateAlias` .. but still ... the fact that we crossed boundaries of current DB.. must come from mapping